# Check if a user has finished typing before the end of a countdown

Tags: c++, countdown

I'm programming an Uno game in C++.

If a player has only two cards in his game, he has to type "Uno" after playing one card. And I want to check if he has finished typing before the end of a countdown (3 sec for example).

How can I do that ? I've looked up the Clock library but without success.

Thanks :)

Comment: Start a separate thread with the timer and send a signal to the original thread when it's up.

Comment: The other way around is easier: after typing, check if it took less than 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to get the time spent waiting for user input:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input); // Wait for user input.
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto timeTaken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count();
std::cout << "Waiting for input took: " << timeTaken << " s" << std::endl;
```